# Do we need “about” in “Employees are unhappy with about low wages”?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I saw the following lead copy of today’s New York Times (May 24) article titled, “Union Effort Turns Its Focus to Target “

“The retailer's employees are unhappy with *about* low wages and short workweeks.”

I have a simple question. Do we need “*about*” after "with"? Isn't this redundant?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like a simple mistake. Writer originally wrote **with**, and changed it to **about**, but forgot to delete the unwanted word.

Disregarding whether that conjecture is actually what happened, there's no question but that using *both* words is incorrect. As *music2myear* says, there are semantic/grammatic reasons for preferring **about**; it may be these are what caused the writer to change his wording. However, it's worth pointing out that over the last 100 years there has been a significant shift in favour of **with**...

[image: my ngram]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper word would be "about", in the sense of the writer meaning "...are unhappy concerning low wages...". "with" is a preposition indicating proximity, which, while it is commonly (ab)used colloquially like this, is not the intended meaning.

Comment: Check out this NGram, showing that things have changed a lot in recent decades. You can't argue the rights and wrongs against that many writers. http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=unhappy+with%2Cunhappy+about&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=10

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I use it myself and recognize it's legitimacy in our evolving language. But if you are looking for the correct usage, let us agree on the original meaning as the goal and accept the newer usages as less than the goal.

Comment: I take your point and will edit my answer accordingly. In this particular case the writer presumably agreed with you, if my conjecture about the 'undeleted' first choice is correct. Not that I think either word is really 'wrong' today, but both together definitely is.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that *about* is to imply around the low, not exactly low.